# Best way to group regions in jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

i need to build a page using jVectorMap where I can show which countries belong to different geopolitical international organisation (such as NATO, UN, BRICK, WTO and so on).

I need to put these regions (which are countries) into groups in such way so when user hovers over some country then other countries become highlighted as well.

What would be a good way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a few series for the regions and then to dynamically change the series for the map.

There is [an example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/) on the jVectorMap website.

Another way to do this is to create a series for the regions and then use the onRegionHover method for the map to iterate over the regions in a range and change the style for  all of them.

Comment: Thx a lot itmitică! Those are great ideas.